# Multi-column grouping in CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file which kinda looks like this:

```
Header1a; Header1b; Header2a;  Header2b;  Header3a...
Value1a;  Value1b;  Value2a;   Value2b;   Value3a...
Value1a;  Value2b;  Value2a;   Value2b;   Value3a...
Value1a;  Value2b;  Value2a;   Value2b;   Value3a...
Value1a;  Value2b;  Value2a;   Value2b;   Value3a...
```

The first row of the file contains the headers, where as each pair of 2 columns belongs to one dataset (`Header1`, `Header2`, `Header3`). The same goes for the actual values: `Value1a` and `Value1b` are a tuple of values belonging to `Header1` and so on...

So:

```
Set 1 (Header 1)  | Set 2 (Header 2)  | Set 3 (Header 3)  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
Value1a, Value1b  | Value2a, Value2b  | Value3a, Value3b  | <-- tuples
Value1a, Value1b  | Value2a, Value2b  | Value3a, Value3b  |
Value1a, Value1b  | Value2a, Value2b  | Value3a, Value3b  |
Value1a, Value1b  | Value2a, Value2b  | Value3a, Value3b  |
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a type for each data set which has a header and a list of tuples denoting the values of the set.

```
class DataSet {
   string Name;
   List<Tuple<string, string>>()
}
```

My approach so far was to get the first line of the CSV file, split it using the separator (;) and take the text from every 2nd item in the array, to get the name of the data set as well as the amount of data sets in the file.

```
var headers = firstLine.Split(new[] { separator }
              .Where((header, index) => index % 2 == 0))
              -> cleanup (Header1a => Header1) etc..
```

and then processing the rest of the rows using grouping:

```
// total amount of columns per row
var columnCount = headers.Count * 2;
var values  = rows
  // split the rows using the separator (;)
  .Select(row => row.Split(new[] { separator })
  // take only those rows which fit the column count (=> headers)
  .Where(columns => columns.Length == columnCount)
  // select the columns by index
  .Select((columns, index) => new { columns, index })

  // now here I want to group the columns of each row into groups of 2 columns
  // but that doesn't actually work, it groups the total amount of rows
  // by groups of 2 rows each
  .GroupBy(group => group.index / 2, group => group.columns)
  .Select(group => group.ToArray());
```

How can I achieve this? I need some way to tell LINQ that it should should group the columns for EACH row, not over all rows, however I can't use `SelectMany()` because else I would lose the individual rows (I'll get a single enumeration of tuples, not an enumeration of an enumeration of tuples.)

Comment: If you really want to use Linq for this create a help method that returns pairs for each line.  The is much easier to write using conventions loops that in linq.  I like linq a lot, but people often use it where it is not meant to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a code example that maybe helps.

First create some sample data, which we can use as source:

```
List<String> data;
{
    var rows = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
    var sets = Enumerable.Range(1, 6);
    var itemsPerSet = Enumerable.Range(1, 2);

    data = rows.Select(rowIndex =>
        String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            String.Join(",", sets.Select(setIndex =>
                String.Join(",", itemsPerSet.Select(itemIndex =>
                    $"Value{rowIndex}-{setIndex}-{itemIndex}")))))).ToList();

    foreach (var row in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));
}
```

Then get the desired data out of it:

```
var selectedColumns = new[] { 0, 1, 4, 5 };

var foo = data.Select(row => row.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                .Where((value, columnIndex) => selectedColumns.Contains(columnIndex)))
              .Select(row => row.Select((Value, ColumnIndex) => new { Value, ColumnIndex })
                                .GroupBy(pair => pair.ColumnIndex / 2)
                                .Select(group => $"Group{group.Key}({String.Join(";", group.Select(pair => pair.Value))})"));

foreach (var row in foo)
{
    foreach (var item in row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```